how to call createPortal only when my target domNode is rendered
I'm working on a React project where I need to create a portal in one component (SectionComponent) to render content inside a target element that exists in a deeply nested or sibling component (GrandChildComponent of ContentComponent). There is no direct parent-child relationship between these components. The component hierarchy looks something like this:
PageComponent
ContentComponent
GrandChildComponent
Target element (div)
SectionComponent
Portal content
Currently, I'm using querySelector to find the target element, but it returns null because the target element isn't available in the DOM when createPortal is called.
How can I ensure that the target element is available when creating the portal? Is there a way to share the target element reference across these components without a direct parent-child relationship?
How can I ensure that the target element is available when creating the portal?
I have tried setInterval to check if my target node is present in the dom. it worked fine. Is there any other way.
